# $R$ commutative ring with with unity. Then: "$(x)$ prime $\iff R$ domain" and "$(x)$ maximal $\iff R$ is a field."

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This is question 7.4.6 from Dummit and Foote. Just need someone to verify my answer.

$$R[x]/(x) \stackrel{\pi}\leftrightsquigarrow R$$

$$a_0 + (a_1 + \dots a_nx^{n-1})x = a_0 + (x) \stackrel{\pi}\leftrightsquigarrow a_0$$

This is clearly an isomorphism with kernel $\ker \pi = (x) = \bar{0} \in R[x]/(x)$. This will answer both question since if $(x)$ is maximal, it is prime. Then $R[x]/(x)$ is a field and hence $R$. Similarly $R[x]/(x)$ would be an integral domain, and so is $R$.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: The ring isomorphism is fine.

Comment: thank you to the both of you.

Comment: @Wuestenfux actually wait my $\pi$ is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd consider the substitution homomorphism $\phi:R[x]\rightarrow R$ defined by $\phi:f(x)\mapsto f(0)$. The kernel is the ideal $I=\langle x\rangle$ and so by the homomorphism theorem, $R[x]/\ker(\phi) = R[x]/\langle x\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\phi(R[x])$ which is $R$, since $\phi$ is surjective. The isomorphism is defined by $f(x)+\langle x\rangle \mapsto f(0)$.

Comment: @Hawk If $a_0+(x)=a_1+(x)$, then $a_0,a_1$ differ by a polynomial divisible by $x$. Since $a_0,a_1$ have degree $0$, this polynomial can only be zero, so indeed $a_0=a_1$.

Comment: @Wojowu so since *this* polynomial $p(x) = 0$, this means $a_0 - a_1 \in (0)$?